# ESP32 sending data of type uint16_t(or anything except for uint8_t and char*) over bluetooth(classic) serial

Tags: serial, bluetooth, esp32

I'm making a custom gamepad with an ESP32 and the joystick output is read by an ADC using `uint16_t analogRead(uint8_t pin);`. Now that I want to send the data and receive and parse it, I ran into a problem. The BluetoothSerial library I'm using only has this function for sending data:

```
size_t write(uint8_t c);
```

And the only other function I know of is this:

```
size_t Print::printf(const char *format, ...);
```

However, I don't want to convert the data to characters. Is there a way of sending integer/float/double etc bytes directly without converting them to characters?

Comment: Send it as two bytes?

Comment: How? I am not very familiar with this type of low level byte manipulation. I'll be glad if someone helped me out :)

Comment: @DaveNewton what's more, how do I distinguish the high and low bytes when they are received at the other end?

Comment: They'll be received in the order sent and can be shoved back together in whatever endian-ness is required. Splitting it up is masking and shifting, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367838/how-to-split-16-value-into-two-8-bit-values-in-c, https://forum.arduino.cc/t/changing-a-16bit-binary-number-into-two-8-bit-byte/44940, and so on.

Comment: @davenewton I have done just that(I searched for it and got the second forum post myself) and got it working with ~93% success rate. It seems that I have to allot a larger buffer than I'm sending or the success rate drops to 15-20%. And by larger buffer I mean at least 3 times larger. I'm sending 4 16-bit integers and I'm using two 0's for the beginning and the end, so I'm checking for that and the known largest ADC integer value after parsing. I also have to time it correctly or it doesn't work (10 ms delay). Is this common?

Comment: Without seeing any code it’s impossible to guess what might be happening.